# Read HTML tags in ios app

Tags: iphone, html

i have a label in my ios app and . from the back end im recieving a description with HTML tags.
EX-:

```
<b>Bold this </b>Sample description<strong>strong text </strong>
```

But unfortunately labels cannot render html tags. is thr any way to do it. without using a webview

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use coretext for that

have a look into this link [Core-Text-Label](https://github.com/newsme/Core-Text-Label)

i hope this will be helpful for you :)